# Changing initially displayed record in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

How to change the first record to be displayed when a Windows Form opens?

I've got a form that retreives data from a table `Table1` within a DataSet `Dataset1` and fills a Details control with the data. When the form is executed, the first record from `table1` shows up in the text fields. How do I change the code so that it displays the record with the key `keyN`?

I'm using Designer, so that the data is delivered via a BindingSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this pattern for programmatically selecting a record on a control bound to a BindingSource:

```
int position = yourBindingSource.Find("YourFieldName", yourRecordValue);
if (position >= 0) {
    yourBindingSource.Position = position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a DataGridView, try

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("AColumn") == "keyN");
```

on the BindingComplete event.